# Can guest access host clipboard despite sharing turned off?

Tags: linux, virtualization, windows-10, clipboard, virtualbox

Host: Win10

Guest: Linux

Software: VirtualBox

Clipboard information might not seem important, but it could very well contain a copied password or other useful data. On the host, clipboard history is also turned on. In VB, both clipboard and file sharing are turned off (disabled).

Despite that, is it still possible for a malware on the guest to access the host's clipboard information or history? Infecting the host or completely breaking out of the VM might be too complicated, but what about just that small aspect?